# How to change the date format in output?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a code that get data from Google Sheet and send emails. However, when I try to get date as dd-mm-yyyy, in the mail it seems "Wed Feb 23 2022 16:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

```
function sendEmails() {
  var EMAIL_SENT = 'Mail Yollandı';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange(1,1).getValue();
  for(var i = 2;i<=lr; i++){
    var MailAddress = ss.getRange(i,1).getValue();
    var RaporBaslangic = ss.getRange(i,2).getValue();
    var RaporBitis = ss.getRange(i,3).getValue();
    var checklist = ss.getRange(i,4).getValue();
    if(checklist !== EMAIL_SENT){
    var currentText = templateText.replace("{Rapor Başlangıç Tarihi}",RaporBaslangic).replace("{Rapor Bitiş Tarihi}",RaporBitis);
    if (checklist !== EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      MailApp.sendEmail(MailAddress,"Sağlık Raporlarının İadesi - Revize",currentText)
      ss.getRange(i, 4).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the date is included in your sheet, use `.getDisplayValue()` instead of `.getValue()`

If you want by script to add the date, use

```
var d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd-MM-yyyy");
```